# Recover some folders from a google cloud VM

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

Is it possible to recover some folders from a google cloud VM which was deleted 1 month back.

My VM got deleted after the trial period was over. I want to recover the VM or at least recover some folders from that VM.

I checked in the snapshot section, there is no snapshot of the deleted VM.

Answer (score 0):

Once your [GCP free trial ends](https://cloud.google.com/free/docs/gcp-free-tier#end), you have 30 days to upgrade your account and save your data. Once the 30 day grace period ends, your data and resources are permanently deleted.